# iOS Restoring IAP works in iOS 15, but not iOS 14.5

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, restore

I'm trying to setup IAP for the first time and I am having problems with the Restore functionality. It works fine in iOS 15 using...

```
        let refresh = SKReceiptRefreshRequest()
        refresh.delegate = self
        refresh.start()

    ...

    func requestDidFinish(_ request: SKRequest) {
        if request is SKReceiptRefreshRequest {
            SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
            SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
        }
        
        request.cancel()
    }
```

...but when I test on an iPhone 11 simulator running iOS 14.5 the `restoreCompletedTransactions` method is reached but no updates are triggered in `paymentQueue`'s `updatedTransactions` delegate method.

I've also noticed that if the iCloud account is not logged in, it doesn't trigger an authentication (which the documentation says should happen).

**Why does the restore code work for iOS 15, but not iOS 14.5?**

and

[Optional, but possibly related:] **How do I trigger the authentication check for iCloud while restoring?**

It's not shown below, but the view has a spinner which starts at the beginning of the restore and is ended by the `completionBlock` passed along when the process starts in the `restore:purchase:completion` method. There's also a modal alert that reports the results when completed. Neither of these are triggering in iOS 14.5.

This is the full class I'm doing the restore in...

```
import StoreKit

final class PurchaseManager: NSObject, SKPaymentTransactionObserver, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKRequestDelegate, CanCreatePopUpMessage {
    
    // MARK: - Properties
    
    var products = [SKProduct]()
        
    var isTesting = false
    
    var completion: OptionalBlock = nil
    
    var productToRestore: Product?
    
    var productsRestored = [Product]()
    
    var failedRestores = [Product]()
    
    // MARK: - Properties: Static
    
    static var shared = PurchaseManager()
    
    // MARK: - Functions

    func restore(purchase: Product, complete: OptionalBlock = nil) {   // <-- Starts here.
        self.completion = complete
        self.productToRestore = purchase

        let refresh = SKReceiptRefreshRequest()
        refresh.delegate = self
        refresh.start()                  // <-- This concludes in requestDidFinish below...
        
//        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
//        SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
        
//        if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
//            let _ = Task {
//                await refreshPurchasedProducts()
//            }
//        }
      }

    ...

    private func restoreFollowUp() {
        for product in productsRestored {
            handleRestore(product)
        }
        
        completion?()
        
        guard let p = productToRestore else { return }
        restoreUpdateAlert(for: p, didFail: !productsRestored.contains(p))
    }

    private func handleRestore(_ product: Product) {
        switch product {
        case .unlock(let gameMode):
            switch gameMode {
            case .defense:
                TrenchesScene.current.infiniteBullets   = true
                TrenchesScene.current.pushAmmo()
            case .offense:
                TrenchesScene.current.unlimitedInfantry = true
                TrenchesScene.current.pushUnitCounts()
            }
        default: break
        }
    }
    
    private func getProduct(from transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) -> Product? {
        getProduct(from: transaction.payment.productIdentifier)
    }
    
    private func getProduct(from transactionId: String) -> Product? {
        switch transactionId {
        case PurchaseId.coin4000         : return .coins(4000)
        case PurchaseId.infiniteAmmo     : return .unlock(.defense)
        case PurchaseId.unlimitedInfantry: return .unlock(.offense)
        default                          : return nil
        }
    }

    ...

    @available(iOS 15.0, *)
    func refreshPurchasedProducts() async {
        self.productsRestored = []
        self.failedRestores = []

        for await verificationResult in Transaction.currentEntitlements {
            switch verificationResult {
            case .verified(let transaction):
                NSLog(" #$ refreshPurchasedProducts verified: \(transaction.productID)")
                if let p = getProduct(from: transaction.productID) {
                    productsRestored.append(p)
                }
                
            case .unverified(let unverifiedTransaction, let verificationError):
                NSLog(" #$ refreshPurchasedProducts unverified: \(unverifiedTransaction.productID),\n #$ error: \(verificationError)")
                if let p = getProduct(from: unverifiedTransaction.productID) {
                    failedRestores.append(p)
                }
            }
        }
        
        restoreFollowUp()
    }
    
    // MARK: - Functions: SKRequestDelegate
    
    func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
        print(" #$ Restore completed transaction count:\(queue.transactions.count)")
        
        for transaction in queue.transactions {
            print("  #$ completed transaction: \(transaction.payment.productIdentifier)")
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - Functions: SKPaymentTransactionObserver
    
    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        transactions.forEach { transaction in
            switch transaction.transactionState {
            case .purchased:  ...
            case .purchasing: ...
            case .restored:
print("   #$ update restoring: \(transaction.payment.productIdentifier)")
                if let p = getProduct(from: transaction) {
                    productsRestored.append(p)
                }
                
                if transaction.transactionIdentifier == transactions.last?.transactionIdentifier {
                    restoreFollowUp()
                }
                
                queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
            case .failed:     ...
            case .deferred:   ...
            @unknown default: ...
            }
        }
    }
    
    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, removedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        NSLog(" #$ Product requests removed: \(transactions.map({ $0.payment.productIdentifier }))")
    }
    
    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError error: Error) {        
        for transaction in queue.transactions {
print(" #$ failed transaction: \(transaction.original?.transactionIdentifier ?? "nil")")
        }
    }
    
    func requestDidFinish(_ request: SKRequest) {
        if request is SKReceiptRefreshRequest {
            SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
            SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
        }
        
        request.cancel()
    }
    
    // MARK: - Functions: SKProductsRequestDelegate

    func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
        products = response.products                
    }
    
    func request(_ request: SKRequest, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        guard request is SKProductsRequest else { return }
        
        // TODO: Handle errors
print(" #$ Product request failed? \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to test IAP on a real device.  Also, adding a payment queue observer is something your app should do in `didFinishLaunching` - Your app needs to be able to handle the delivery of incomplete transactions soon after launch.

Comment: I already have other behaviors happening on app launch (e.g. getting products, etc...), but the documentation specifically says not to do restore on launch because it is supposed to trigger authentication. Also, I test on real devices but for older OS versions I use the simulator.

Comment: No, you should not restore, that is correct. Your first code block in your question shows you adding a payment queue observer. You should not need to do this as you should already have one in place soon after launch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue wasn't OS version at all, but it had to do with testing on simulators (as @paulw11 mentioned in comments).

Under normal conditions, a user with the same apple id on multiple devices should be able to do a purchase on one and then restore on the other. THIS IS NOT HOW IT WORKS ON SIMULATORS.

I assumed that I could just hit restore on a new simulator and that it should retrieve transactions, but for testing purposes simulators need to have the purchase happen on each device, regardless of account.